# Как пользоваться Path?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как пользоваться Path? В частности как с его помощью нарисовать крестик?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример с кнопкой Close:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="CloseButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Name="BG"/>
                    <Path Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Fill" Name="PATH"
                          Data="M 0 0 M 0.3 0.3 L 0.7 0.7 M 0.3 0.7 L 0.7 0.3 M 1 1"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BG" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PATH" Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Применение:

```
<Button Width="30" Height="30" Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}"/>
```

Получаем:

[image: крестик]

Вкратце: для `Path` определён внутренний язык. `M` означает «перейти, ничего не рисуя». `L` означает «нарисовать». У получившейся картинки берётся описывающий прямоугольник, и растягивается пропорционально на весь размер контрола.

В нашем случае:

1. `M 0 0`: ставим невидимую точку с координатами (0, 0)
2. `M 0.3 0.3`: переходим к точке (0.3, 0.3)
3. `L 0.7 0.7`: рисуем линию до точки (0.7, 0.7)
4. `M 0.3 0.7`: переходим к точке (0.3, 0.7)
5. `L 0.7 0.3`: рисуем линию до (0.7, 0.3)
6. `M 1 1`: переходим к точке (1, 1)

Шаги 1 и 6 нужны для того, чтобы описывающий прямоугольник не примыкал прямо к краям крестика.

Вот описание всего синтаксиса: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: А инструментов нет, которые визуально помогают рисовать, хотя бы на уровне пейнта?

Comment: @Monk Microsoft Expression Blend

Comment: @Monk: Или клетчатая бумага и карандаш :)

Comment: @VladD на самом деле я еще до вашего ответа уже разобрался. :) Вот тут хорошо расписано: http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/graphics_and_animation/level13/13_5.php

Comment: @DarkByte: Отлично! Вот вам ещё один патрон в обойму.

Comment: @Monk Path использует SVG нотацию, можно рисовать в любом SVG редакторе и потом просто копировать